# Function leaking memory yet is freed

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am confused as to why this function is leaking memory. It is supposed to detect checkmate in a chess recreation. It uses `legal_moves()`, which assigns a pointer to a head of a list of legal moves (`save` here) and `king_under_check()`, which returns a boolean value. When I run it through `valgrind`, I am getting a definite memory leak. Am I wrong to assume that per the `valgrind` output this function is where the leak originates?

My function:

```
    Bool is_checkmate(PlayerColor c) {

    Move *list = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
    Move *save = list;
    unsigned int num = 0;
    if(is_king_under_check(c) && !legal_moves(&save, c, &num)){
      freeList(save);
      return TRUE;
    }
    freeList(save);
    return FALSE;
    }
```

and I use `freeList()` to free the list written to in `legal_moves()`:

```
    void freeList(Move *head){
    Move *temp;

    while(head != NULL){
        temp = head;    
        head = head->next_move;
        free(temp);
    }   

Here is the `valgrind` output:
```

```
    ==447557== 111,504 bytes in 4,646 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 44 of 47
    ==447557==    at 0x4837B65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
    ==447557==    by 0x116E55: is_checkmate (moves.c:1430)
    ==447557==    by 0x1172BF: run_mate1 (moves.c:1486)
    ==447557==    by 0x117CBD: run_mate2 (moves.c:1599)
    ==447557==    by 0x109C37: main (main.c:181)
```

Here is my (quite long) legal moves function to may narrow down the issue:

```
Bool legal_moves(Move **m, PlayerColor c, unsigned int *pcount) {
     /* Your implementation */
     Board tempBoard = CurrentBoard;
     uint64_t sq;
     Move *save = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
     Move *link = save;
     *m = save;
     Move possibleMove;
     /*Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));*/
     unsigned int i, shift;
     for(shift = 0; shift < 64; shift++){
       /*printf("move count%d\n",*pcount);*/
       sq = 1;
       sq = sq<<shift;
       if(player[c].k & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = KING;
         Pos *k_moves = king_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(k_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = k_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].k, KING, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].k, KING, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c) == TRUE){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;

           }
           else if((board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == NORTH_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == EAST_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == SOUTH_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == EAST_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == SW_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == SE_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == NE_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k))) ||
               (board_to_pos(player[BLACK].k) == NW_OF(board_to_pos(player[WHITE].k)))){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }

           else if(detect_castle_move(possibleMove, c) == 1){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             if(is_castling_valid(c) == TRUE){
                 Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
                 mNode->from = shift;
                 mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
                 mNode->piece = KING;
                 mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
                 mNode->next_move = NULL;

                 player[c] = temp;
                 player[1-c] = temp2;
                 CurrentBoard = tempBoard;

                 link = save;
                 while(link->next_move != NULL){
                    link = link->next_move;
                 }
                 link->next_move = mNode;
                 (*pcount)++;
                /*free(mNode);*/
              }

           }
           else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = KING;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
            /*free(mNode);*/
           }
         }
            free(k_moves);
         }
       }

       if(player[c].b & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = BISHOP;
         Pos *b_moves = bishop_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(b_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = b_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].b, BISHOP, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].b, BISHOP, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c) == TRUE){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = BISHOP;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
            /* free(mNode);*/
           }
         }
            free(b_moves);
         }
       }
       if(player[c].p & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = PAWN;
         Pos *p_moves = pawn_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(p_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = p_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           possibleMove.promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];

           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].p, PAWN, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           if(RANK_OF(possibleMove.to) == '1' || RANK_OF(possibleMove.to) == '8'){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             int j = 0;
             for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                 Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
                 mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
                 mNode->from = shift;
                 mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
                 mNode->piece = PAWN;
                 mNode->next_move = NULL;
                 if(j == 0) mNode->promotion_choice = QUEEN;
                 if(j == 1) mNode->promotion_choice = ROOK;
                 if(j == 2) mNode->promotion_choice = BISHOP;
                 if(j == 3) mNode->promotion_choice = NIGHT;
                 player[c] = temp;
                 player[1-c] = temp2;
                 CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
                 link = save;
                 while(link->next_move != NULL){
                    link = link->next_move;
                 }
                 link->next_move = mNode;
                 (*pcount)++;
                /*free(mNode);*/
             }

           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].p, PAWN, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c) == TRUE){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }

           else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = PAWN;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
            /* free(mNode);*/
           }
         }
            free(p_moves);
         }
       }
       if(player[c].r & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = ROOK;
         Pos *r_moves = rook_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(r_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = r_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].r, ROOK, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].r, ROOK, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c) == TRUE){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = ROOK;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
           }
         }
            free(r_moves);
         }

       }
       if(player[c].n & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = NIGHT;
         Pos *n_moves = knight_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(n_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = n_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].n, NIGHT, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].n, NIGHT, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c) == TRUE){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = NIGHT;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
             /*free(mNode);*/
           }
          }
            free(n_moves);
         }
       }
       if(player[c].q & sq){
         possibleMove.from = shift;
         possibleMove.piece = QUEEN;
         Pos *q_moves = queen_move(possibleMove, c);
         unsigned int size = *(q_moves);
         unsigned int *arrPtr = q_moves;
         if(size > 0){
         for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++){
           possibleMove.to = *(arrPtr + i);
           PlayerState temp = player[c];
           PlayerState temp2 = player[1-c];
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             make_move(possibleMove, player[c].q, QUEEN, c);
             if(is_king_under_check(c)){
               player[c] = temp;
               player[1-c] = temp2;
               CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
               continue;
             }
           }
           player[c] = temp;
           player[1-c] = temp2;
           CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           make_move(possibleMove, player[c].q, QUEEN, c);
           if(is_king_under_check(c)){
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
           }else{
             Move *mNode = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
             mNode->from = shift;
             mNode->to = *(arrPtr + i);
             mNode->piece = QUEEN;
             mNode->promotion_choice = UNKNOWN;
             mNode->next_move = NULL;
             player[c] = temp;
             player[1-c] = temp2;
             CurrentBoard = tempBoard;
             link = save;
             while(link->next_move != NULL){
                link = link->next_move;
             }
             link->next_move = mNode;
             (*pcount)++;
             /*free(mNode);*/
           }

         }
            free(q_moves);
        }
       }
     }
     if(*pcount > 0){
       return TRUE;
     }else{
       return FALSE;
     }
 }
```

And the associated `valgrind` output:

```
==447557== 535,008 (12,792 direct, 522,216 indirect) bytes in 533 blocks 
are definitely lost in loss record 47 of 47
==447557==    at 0x4837B65: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
==447557==    by 0x10CA10: legal_moves (moves.c:24)
==447557==    by 0x117059: run_mate1 (moves.c:1464)
==447557==    by 0x117CBD: run_mate2 (moves.c:1599)
==447557==    by 0x109C37: main (main.c:181)
```

Comment: `legal_moves(&save, c, &num))` - if that modifies `save`, and does not free what it pointed to coming in, then the original `list` is leaked. I suspect the usefulness of `list` is questionable (i.e. the `calloc` is pointless), and in fact `save` should start as `NULL` from inception, but that sheer wag (wild-arse-guess) is based entirely on what `legal_moves` actually does with its pointer-to-pointer provided argument.

Comment: You are passing `&save` to `legal_moves()`, that function probably modifies the value of `save` and you end up freeing something else.

Comment: Yeah, `*m = save;` near the top of your `legal_moves` function instantly leaks the original pointer `save` had in your first function. Get rid of that `list` and `calloc`, initialize `save` as `NULL`, and send it in. It will probably be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `legal_moves()` function:

```
Move *save = (Move *)(calloc(1, sizeof(Move)));
Move *link = save;
*m = save;
```

Here you just completely lost any reference to the allocated memory that was passed by reference to the function, and there's no way of freeing it (actually, you still have `list` in `is_checkmate()`, but you don't use it). If `legal_moves()` does the allocation on its own, then there's no point in doing it prior to calling it in `is_checkmate()` (or anywhere else the function is used).

You could do:

```
Move *save = NULL;
unsigned int num = 0;
if (is_king_under_check(c) && !legal_moves(&save, c, &num)){
    // ...
}
```

Also, as a rule of thumb: [don't cast the result of malloc/calloc/realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I see, thank you. Though I still am getting a leak of 163,000 bytes (indirectly lost, same as the second output I posted, but less bytes) after going through the code and changing all the pointers passed into legal_moves(). Might you have any suggestions?

Comment: Follow what `valgrind` says and when you find the variable try following through the code to see how the variable gets used. It's what I did to catch the error in your question.